# C++/CX: Defining public void at namespace scope

Tags: javascript, namespaces, scope, c++-cx, abi

Is it possible to define a public void at the namespace scope (that can pass through ABI and later be used inside an JavaScript project)? Of course, "public void update(int param);" doesn't work as public seems to be invalid keyword in this context. The alternative is to make a class to hold that method but I would like to avoid that and have a function at the namespace scope.

Thanks

Comment: remove the public part and it will work as global in the namespace?

Comment: It will but it doesn't pass through ABI therefore it cannot be called from the JavaScript project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have a namespace-scope function that goes across the ABI.  I recommend making a wrapper class and making the function a static.